# In a Linq Expression body how to use the value of a variable instead of a reference to it?

Tags: c#, linq

Here is my code:

```
IQueryable<DAL.TradeCard> data = dc.TradeCard.Include("Address").Include("Vehicle");

string orderNumber = "ORD_NR_2";
Expression<Func<DAL.TradeCard, bool>> whereClause = a => a.orderNumber == orderNumber;

// Expression<Func<DAL.TradeCard, bool>> whereClause = a => a.orderNumber == "ORD_NR_2";

List<DAL.TradeCard> dataAsList = data.Where(whereClause).ToList();
```

If I use the commented line, then the value of whereClause will look like this:

> {a => (a.orderNumber == "ORD_NR_2")}

If instead of the commented line I use the other definiton then the value of whereClause will look like this:

> {a => (a.orderNumber ==
>   value(app_Employee.UI.UserFunctions.LejelentettTetelek+<>c__DisplayClass0).orderNumber)}

This is a problem, because I want to save the whereClause and use it in other places where the orderNumber variable does not exist.
So how to use the value of the orderNumber variable instead of a reference to it in a Linq expression. I want to make "**value(app_Employee.UI.UserFunctions.LejelentettTetelek+<>c__DisplayClass0).orderNumber**" into "**ORD_NR_2**".

Comment: "I want to save the whereClause and use it in other places where the orderNumber variable does not exist." Can you show the code where this isn't working? What behaviour are you getting vs what behaviour you expect?

Comment: your local `orderNumber` save as field auto generated class `app_Employee.UI.UserFunctions.LejelentettTetelek+<>c__DisplayClass0` for using inside closure, so you can use this where clause somewhere else

Answer (score 4):

The code in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2007/08/01/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-iii.aspx) *(Link is dead, Archived version: https://web.archive.org/web/20160122054419/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2007/08/01/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-iii.aspx)* provides a way to evaluate all sections of an expression into values, in all of the places that it can be done.

First it walks through the expression tree from the bottom up, indicating which objects don't have an parameter objects as any of their children.  Then it walk through the tree from the top down, evaluating all expressions to a value that don't have a parameter in them.

We can also create an additional method specifically for an expression representing a `Func` with one parameter so that you don't need to do the cast when you call it:

```
public static Expression<Func<TIn, TOut>> Simplify<TIn, TOut>(
    this Expression<Func<TIn, TOut>> expression)
{
    return (Expression<Func<TIn, TOut>>)Evaluator.PartialEval(expression);
}
```

This allows you to write:

```
string orderNumber = "ORD_NR_2";
Expression<Func<DAL.TradeCard, bool>> whereClause = a => a.orderNumber == orderNumber;
string foo = whereClause.Simplify().ToString();
//foo will be "{a => (a.orderNumber == "ORD_NR_2")}"
```